# Sort Jquery elements if it has it has attribute value of 1 or higher and place at bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where i need to sort jquery elements if it has attribute value of 1 or higher

```
selectors = "a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]";
var test = $("body").find(selectors);
```

now i need to sort the test variable if it has attribute tabindex of 1 or higher and place at the bottom of Array or object in order

Note: Don't sort if tabindex is 0

Why i need this ?

This will help me determine the last focussable element in body.

i know this is kinda tricky question but i dont see any other way to find the last focussable element

Comment: Sort? all this elements are dispersed all around your page, right?

Comment: Yes i only need to sort the tabindex elements whose value is 1 or higher and leave the remaining in the same place

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
selectors = "a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]";
var test = $("body").find(selectors);
test.sort(function(a,b) {
   // Replace b and a below if you wan't descending order
   return $(b).attr("tabindex") < $(a).attr("tabindex");
});
```

Comment: Thanks it helped to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own as this may help some one in need

what i did is i added one more variable separating the tabindex 0

```
selectors = "a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex=0], *[contenteditable]",
higherselectors = "*[tabindex]:not([tabindex=0]):not([tabindex=-1])";
var test1 = $("body").find(selectors);
var test2 = $("body").find(higherselectors);
if(test2.length) {
  test2.toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).attr('tabindex') < $(b).attr('tabindex');
  });
}
```

Finally the first focussable element of the body will be test2[0] and the last focussable element of the body will be test1[test.length-1]

please check appropriate conditions